# How can I tell on which page a Buy Now button was pushed?

Tags: paypal

I have a Buy Now button on a blog, it links to the same product from every page, but I'd like to know from which page the user came to purchase the product - is there a way to do it without making a different product from every page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom field (256 chars) to track page source. This is a pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which buyers do not see.

Comment: I will see that info in the receipt page?